# Make seeks dependencies in a directory before switching to it?

Tags: makefile

I tried to write a `make` rule of this form:

```
lib%.so: computations/%.h
        make -C computations/ -f makefile $<
```

Output:

```
make -C computations/ -f makefile computations/test.h
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/shai/csm/csm2/src/computations'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `computations/test.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shai/csm/csm2/src/computations'
make: *** [libtest.so] Error 2
```

Well, it seems that it looks for `%.h` after switching library. No biggie, I'll just try removing

```
lib%.so: %.h
        make -C computations/ -f makefile $<
```

but now it doesn't recognize the rule at all!

Output:

```
shai@ubuntu:~/csm/csm2/src$ make libtest.so
`make: *** No rule to make target `libtest.so'.  Stop.
```

Is `make` playing with my mind? How could a change in the **dependencies** make it stop recognizing the **target**?

Comment: By the way, I only just noticed this is an odd rule. It updates the dependency, not the target. That's not how `make` is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

> How could a change in the dependencies make it stop recognizing the target?

Most likely because it can't find a file that fits the pattern of the dependency, because `test.h` is in another directory. You could use `VPATH` to have it search for files in other directories.

Edit: but this still won't fix your problem completely, because `$<` will be substituted by `computations/test.h`, which won't be found in the directory `computations` (as in the first error you got). You might try `$(notdir $<)`, but I think it's an ugly hack (if it works; I haven't tried it). This results from the design of your makefile and project structure.

Answer (score 2):

You're using make wrong.

Make's design is actually fairly simple at heart: you tell it

1. how to create targets                  (The body of the rule).
2. which targets it needs to create first (The dependency list).

Make then [topological sorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the  dependency information so it executes the bodies in the right order.

Your rule with `$<` (which expands to the list of dependencies) means you're telling the invoked make to create the dependency `%.h` not the target `lib%.so`.
The rule has to create the target.  If the dependency needs to be created, you need to tell make how to do so with another, separate rule, not try to ensure it is up to date in this rule.

As you're trying to coordinate across directories, I'll recommend the paper [Recursive make considered harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/), which can often be a nice way to organize things, though not the only possible way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be the way you copy/pasted it, but you're missing a tab in the second form.

Comment: Then, I don't know.  I'm just as baffled as you are.